# 6 Floating digit without separator in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get 11001   as 11001.000000 , I tried ToString("N6"), but it adds separator and output is as: 11,001.000000
 How can get the value as a 6 floating digit without separator?

Comment: without *thousand* separator

Answer (score 3):

Use `F6` instead of `N6`

```
int i = 11001;
string result = i.ToString("F6");
```

Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 11001;
string result = i.ToString("F6");
```

Here `F` in `ToString()` method is fixed point format specifier.
Number next to `F` can be used accordingly.

**ex** if you want `11001.00000`, then use `ToString("F5");`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the comma separaytor use can use

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator
```

---

```
double d = 11001;
string result = d.ToString("F6").Replace(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator, "");
```